# PHP Fatal error: Switch statements may only contain one default clause in httpdocs\careers.php

Tags: php, iis, mime-types

I have a php script which uploads pdf files to the server. The code is working fine on local environment (XAMPP) but not on live server (IIS - Plesk).

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

$ok = false;
switch (finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
   
   case 'application/pdf':
        
        $ok = true;
        break;
   default:
        echo '<script>alert("Your resume is not a PDF file. Upload PDF file only!"); window.history.back();</script>';
       die();
}
$pimage=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"resume_upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

The error log shows **PHP Fatal error: Switch statements may only contain one default clause in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\careers.php**

What is this error? I have googled a lot but couldn't find a solution. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Are you sure that posted code is the place where this error is happening, because there doesn't seem to be multiple `default` clauses. The reason why it works in local environment, but not in live might be differing PHP versions. Multiple default clauses throw an error since 7.0.

Comment: Are you certain your error applies to the code and the switch above?

Comment: Yes, this is the code. I don't have complete access to the live server. So I cannot change or view the php version or the settings.

Comment: When submitting the form, the server returns HTTP 500 error

Comment: Unless something really really weird is going on this can't be the offending part of careers.php. Because there's only one default clause in posted switch statement. There's either more switch statements in that file or the file in live server isn't the same as you've posted here.

Comment: @Hendrik I have changed the switch statement to IF condition but the server still returns 500 error. I think the server is blocking mime check because of some configuration/security issue(?) Is that possible?

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information about 500 error.